# Parameter value '100' out of range

Tags: sql-server-2008, types

I have a SQL Server 2008 column table with type `Numeric(4, 0)`.

I'm using a ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and that column is mapped as a `Decimal?` type.

Whne I try to insert a 100 value and get that error message.

Do you know why? If I want to store numbers from 0 to 999, which is the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go with `smallint`, range:-2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767), 2 Bytes

Comment: BTW that will be represented in .NET as `System.Int16`

Comment: I'm using Decimal with precision = 4.

Comment: @VansFannel, check my comment above using `smallint` vs `numeric[(p[,s])]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a smallint with a check constraint that makes sure that only values between 0 and 999 are allowed

Comment: And what about SQL Server Data type? Is it correct to use `Numeric(4,0)`?

Comment: @VansFannel, for your purpose you want to use `smallint`, which is 2 bytes of storage, even the smallest `numeric[(p[,s])]` data type will be 5 bytes of storage